# Log4j2 custom Filter xml to property file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j2

Created the custom filter by extending AbstractFilter. 
Created log4j2.xml as per below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30"  
packages="com.smp.marker">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="DEFAULT_LOG_PATTERN">%d %-5p  %m%n  [:%L]</Property>
 </Properties>
 <Appenders>
    <Console name="CLOG" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
   <PatternLayout alwaysWriteExceptions="false" pattern="%d %-5p 
[%c{5}.%M():%L] %m%n" />
   <Filters>
     <SmpClogAppenderFilter level="ALL" onMatch="ACCEPT" 
onMismatch="DENY"/> 
   </Filters>
 </Console>
 <Console name="DEFAULT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout alwaysWriteExceptions="false" 
pattern="${DEFAULT_LOG_PATTERN}" />
    <Filters>
      <SmpClogAppenderFilter level="ALL" onMatch="DENY" 
onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
    </Filters>
  </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
 <Root level="info">
   <AppenderRef ref="CLOG" />
   <AppenderRef ref="DEFAULT" />
 </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is working as expetced.
But in our project we need log4j2.properties.
Unable to create the property file with custom filter.Mainly need propety value for filter section.

```
<Filters>
 <SmpClogAppenderFilter level="ALL" onMatch="ACCEPT"
```

onMismatch="DENY"/>

Could some one please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using MarkerFilter?

Comment: Thank you for replying. No I am not using.

Comment: You said "in our project we need log4j2.properties" - why? The choice of format is a matter of preference, not a technical requirement.

Comment: I have upgrade project from log4j1 to log4j2. In log4j1 it was using log4j.properties so maintaining same thing for log4j2 also.